# Traefik sticky session not working in docker swarm

Tags: session, cookies, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a problem in Traefik reverse proxy: it uses an own cookie to store the backend server ip address, but sometimes this is not working properly because the path of the cookie is not `'/'` but it uses the webpage default for instance `'/myapp/page'`.

My problem is that the application also uses an other path like `'/myapp/api'`, but that is routed to another instance.

As it is a legacy application I cannot store the session data in an other external session store. I use docker swarm to manage docker containers.

How can I set the path of the cookie in Traefik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you cannot customize the cookie path -- Traefik currently does not set it at all (which is [a known issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/1744)).

There have been [considerations](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/1744#issuecomment-308872379) in the directions of always setting the root path (`/`) and/or determining the path from the frontend path. Feel free to chime in on the existing issue or create a new one if you feel that Traefik is missing a need for customization in this regard.